# How to install OpenSSH 7 or higher on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ssh

On CentOS 7, I am only able to install OpensSH server 6.6.1 and can't seem to install any latest one. How to install OpenSSH 7 or higher?

Comment: Download from source and install generally works the best.

Comment: @FrankThornton, is there any chance you could provide a more detailed answer in addition to your useful comment?

Comment: If you tell us the reason for wanting OpenSSH 7, it's possible somebody may be able to provide more useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for CentOS 7.4 which brings OpenSSH 7.4 out of the box, as you can see in the [Beta Release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/7.4_Release_Notes/new_features_security.html).